# Cannot get rid of transparency in my navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a configuration class from which I set the appearance for the navigation bar:

```
final class AppearanceConfigurator: Configurable {
  func configure() {
    let mainColor = R.color.main()
    let secondaryColor = R.color.white()

    setupNavigationBar(mainColor: mainColor, secondaryColor: secondaryColor)
    setupControls(mainColor: mainColor, secondaryColor: secondaryColor)

    let appearance = UIToolbarAppearance()
    appearance.backgroundColor = secondaryColor
  }

  private func setupNavigationBar(mainColor: UIColor?, secondaryColor: UIColor?) {
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    let navigationBarAppearance = getNavigationBarAppearance(backgroundColor: mainColor,
                                                             textColor: secondaryColor)

    navigationBar.barTintColor = secondaryColor
    navigationBar.tintColor = secondaryColor
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
  }

  private func getNavigationBarAppearance(backgroundColor: UIColor?, textColor: UIColor?) -> UINavigationBarAppearance {
    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    
    if let textColor = textColor {
        navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: textColor]
        navigationBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: textColor]
    }
    return navigationBarAppearance
  }

  private func setupControls(mainColor: UIColor?, secondaryColor: UIColor?) {
    UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = secondaryColor
    UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = mainColor
    UIButton.appearance().tintColor = secondaryColor
    UILabel.appearance().tintColor = secondaryColor
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = secondaryColor
    UIRefreshControl.appearance().tintColor = secondaryColor
  }
}
```

However, the color of the navigation bar is somehow transparent. What am I missing? I've set translucent to false and also passed standard appearance as I should have

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a new project without changing anything, and tested it on a `UINavigationBar` set up in `Main.storyboard` and connected with an `IBOutlet`.  Then I called your function like this `setupNavigationBar(mainColor: .yellow, secondaryColor: .systemIndigo)` inside `viewDidLoad`.  The background view was bright red.  I couldn't see any red through the bar or the bar item.  Both the yellow background and the indigo text seemed opaque, so I'm not sure your problem is 100% reproducible from this example.

Comment: Are you using a regular view controller with a `UINavigationBar` added (this is what I tested) or are you using the `UINavigationController`?

Comment: UINavigationController

Comment: I'll try again with that and let you know how it turns out

Comment: ok, weird thing, but I fixed it by applying status bar in target -> deployment info -> lightContent

Comment: however, I don't necessarily know why is that so

Comment: Just saw your comment after testing with a `UINavigationController` and again being unable to replicate the problem (it was still opaque for me).  Glad you found a solution!  I'm not familiar with that setting and it isn't something I would have thought to test.

Comment: Thanks you all for trying to help. After iOS 15 NavigationAppearance, NavigationBar etc. became troublesome to me